# show 10 items in each row of recycler view with grid layout similar to flipkart app

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on e-commerce app. I want to design home page similar to Flipkart app.I have used recycler view.I am able to display data successfully but what I want is to display first 10 elements from list in 1 row i.e. 1 to 10. In 2 row items shouls be from 11 to 20.

Right now its showing 1 to 15 items in all rows as my list size is 15.

Screenshot attached.
[image]
Code for adapter-

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter3 extends               RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter3.RecyclerViewHolders> {

//private List<ItemObject> itemList;
private List<String> itemList2;
private Context context;
private static final int ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_HEADER = 0;
private static final int ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 1;
private  View header;
private GridLayoutManager lLayout;

public RecyclerViewAdapter3(Context context) {
   // this.itemList = itemList;
  //  this.itemList2=itemList2;
    this.context = context;
}






@Override
public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Log.i("pos on create holder",""+viewType);
 /*   if (viewType ==  ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_HEADER) {
        return new RecyclerViewHolders(header);
    }else {*/
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, null);
        RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
        return rcv;
   // }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
    List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList();

   /* LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);*/
    //layoutManager.scrollToPosition(currPos);


   lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(context, 1, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

   // lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(context, 10);
    int spacingInPixels = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.spacing);
   // holder.rView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(spacingInPixels));


   // lLayout.setFullSpan(true);
    holder.rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    holder.rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);
    final RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(context, rowListItem);
    holder.rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 5;
}



public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public RecyclerView rView;

    public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        rView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    }


}

private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList(){

    List<ItemObject> allItems = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("United States", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Canada", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("United Kingdom", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Germany", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Sweden", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("United Kingdom", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Germany", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Sweden", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("United States", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Canada", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("United Kingdom", R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    return allItems;
}
```

}

Comment: May be everyone of the community is not using the flipkart app, paste some picture if you want to achieve something graphically similar.

Comment: @nobalG - just check it properly.....screenshot is attached already...and its not compulsory to use flipkart app...it can be any e-commerce app....every app has almost same basic ui.

Comment: can you try to use horizontal scroll view ?if not then take one horizontal scroll view and put your each item dynamically into that view you can easily get that kind of view.

Comment: final RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(context, rowListItem); is what you are passing in list just pass number of elements you want suppose you need first 5 items of that list then just get first five item from list and pass it in adapter.